# Telerik RAD Controls, how to set a List(Of GridViewRowInfo) as a RadGridView DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm looking for a C# or VB.NET solution for this.

---

> UPDATE:

I have a RadGridView with 5 manualy defined columns by me:
[image]

`AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to `False`.

When I instace a `GridViewRowInfo` class I can set a lot of properties for this object:

```
Dim MyRow As New GridViewRowInfo(Me.RadGridView1.MasterView)
With MyRow
    .Cells(0).Value = "My Value for Column 1"
    .Cells(1).Value = "My Value for Column 2"
    .Cells(2).Value = "My Value for Column 3"
    .Cells(3).Value = "My Value for Column 4"
    .Cells(4).Value = "My Value for Column 5"
    .Height = 50
    .Tag = New Object
    .IsSelected = True
End With
```

And when I add that row the properties that I've previously set for that row takes effect inmediately:

```
RadGridView1.Rows.Add(MyRow)
```

[image]

If I want to add a collection of those rows just I can set a new collection of `GridViewRowInfo` that implements the `IList` interface:

```
Dim MyRows As New List(Of GridViewRowInfo)
MyRows.Add(MyRow1)
MyRows.Add(MyRow2)
MyRows.Add(MyRow3)

RadGridView1.Rows.AddRange(MyRows.ToArray)
```

Well, so my intention is to set a collection of those rows as `DataSource`, for example:

```
RadGridView1.DataSource = MyRows
```

So the first thing to notice is that I've set a collection of `GridViewRowInfo` and I've set different properties for each `GridViewRowInfo` that should take effect when adding the datasource-collection, the second thing is that if I update the datasource-collection to remove or add more rows then the `RadGridView` control should perform the updates automatically without more intervention ...not?

The problem is that any of those things happens:

[image]

As you could see in the image above, when I set a `List(of GridViewRowInfo)` as my `DataSource`, it only adds empty rows, and if I previously have set for example the `Height` property of one of the `GridViewRowInfo` inside it does not take effect when setting the `Datasource`:

I would like to perform this in the more direct way and the less extravagant way, I mean i'm not looking for create a custom class to be able to set that class as `DataSource`, and reproducing all the properties that exposes the `GridViewRowInfo` class or something so tricky in my custom class, 'cause If the `RadGridView` exposes a good `GridViewRowInfo` class with all that I need why I should consider to create a custom class to set it aa my  `DataSource`?.

If I don't have a good idea or a missunderstanding of these concepts please clarify me them, I know that the usage of the datasource should not be used in that way (or I think so) but I really would like to do it to simplify the things even more to work directly with the datasource (and each row property) instead the control itself.

---

Also I've tried the oficial example in [this link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-generic-list.html) (but just using a `list(Of String)` instead), but it just adds a new column in my gridview named 'Length' (with a numeric data) in that column cell.

Comment: are you setting up RadGridView's columns manually or just leaving it auto generated?

Comment: @har07 I've set 4 columns manualy, sorry for my ignorance but I don't know why this matter, I would like to set a List(of 'CompatibleRowForMyGrid') like in the example above then with those 4 cells to fill the data in my columns, I don't want to generate new columns, I wait for your help, thanks for comment!

Comment: the way it generally works is the control does much of the work you are trying to force on them with that datasource - simplify the class to 4 simple properties and leave off the `Cells` cruft.  If AutoGenerate is True then it will create columns for each property it finds (see the example link where the columns are `MyInt` and `MyString` which are the prop names).  If you want your DS to populate existing columns you added, you need to map Columns to Properties using the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` (and maybe `FieldName`).

Comment: `Simplify the class to 4 simple properties and leave off the Cells cruft.` What Class? my intention is not to create a custom class, I'm using a GridViewRowInfo class. | `If AutoGenerate is True then it will create columns for each property it finds` After reading that I've set `AutoGenerateColumns` as False (but now it adds empty rows).

Comment: `If you want your DS to populate existing columns you added, you need to map Columns to Properties using the DisplayMember and ValueMember (and maybe FieldName)` And they are members of...? I can't see those properties on the RadGridView control or the GridViewRowInfo Class, anyways once found I don't know how to set them (seeying this maybe could be a little difficult). Thankyou for comment!

Comment: you are mixing manual row adding (code sample above) with the method for a bound datasource. See [Binding to Generic Lists](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-generic-list.html) see also http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-generating-columns.html for manually adding columns and adding the binding props (DisplayMember etc)

Comment: As I'm trying to say my intention is to add a collection or `GridViewRowInfo`, Why?, because I can set directly all the properties of the GridViewRowInfo object for each row when adding one row into the list such as the row height, the row style, etc. that way would be really useful than creating a custom class with 5 properties for 5 columns.

Comment: I am trying to say that is not how they work. A `DataSource` supplies *data* not control properties - they are 2 different things and it wont read Column, row or control props from a datasource.   Your datasource will require more work than a plain class: yours has a sub collection (cells) and all of them have the same Property name (Value).  All of this is likely to confuse the control.  At a minimum, you will have to tell it the FieldName to display (not sure how to do that with a subcollection).

Comment: So plutonix then this means that I'm asking more or less for some kind of hack? really is hard to udnerstand for me why if the RadGridView works with GridViewRowInfo as rows then why doesnt's automatically will allow the parsing of a datasource that contains those rows, really that requires some hard work? I don't know how to proceed. thanks for comment

Comment: `why doesnt [it] automatically allow the parsing of a datasource that contains those rows` Because that is not how it works with any datasource in NET.  The controls all create rows (or items) for you from the datasource; if you create and embed a bunch of rows in the datasource, you are asking it to create rows from rows.  It gets confused and fails.  None of the examples there show putting rows in a datasource.  Data goes in List<T>, Collection<T>, datatables etc.

Comment: I've tried also with a `Dim rows As New GridViewRowCollection(Me.RadGridView1.Templates.Owner)` as datasource, it only adds empty rows, I understand more or less why it does not works but would be great to set it as the datasource...

Comment: You are incorrectly using the grid - as Plutonix has said, the control layout and the control datasource are two separate things - you need to specify the column definitions for your grid and point them to properties on your data source. Your data source can be any object but the grid decides how many rows it should display based on the object type (e.g. it checks for `IEnumerable` interface to see if the object is enumerable etc). What the columns are called and what they display is up to you (or you can auto-generate columns - the control will inspect the properties on the data source)

Comment: The bottom line is, your data source is just data - if you want your datasource to format your cells, you need to bind some of the properties on your grid to valid values in the datasource or use the grids events to decide what to do by writing code. Usually for grids there is a `RowDataBound` event or some such which is fired when each row is bound to the data source, in this you can check the data item properties and decide how to format the cell. `GridViewRowInfo` is likely used internally and you cannot touch the parts of the control that it is intended for. You can only bind.

Comment: @Charles thanks, I've read the description of the row events but I can't find any related to the datasource, RowDataBound doesn't exists (at least is not public)

Comment: What tech are you using? Winforms/WFP/Silverlight? It looks like Winforms...

Comment: For Winforms you can use `CellFormatting` events to format cells: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-cells-formatting-cells.html - inspect the datasource when the event fires and set the format accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If I don't have a good idea or a missunderstanding of these concepts please clarify them`

You are confusing WHAT to display with HOW to display them which are 2 very different things. From their online guide: `The RadGridView supports the standard Windows Forms data binding model` which is to say the datasource provides *data* for the control, not presentation information.

```vb
Public Class MyObject
   Public Property MyInt() As Integer
   Public Property MyString() As String
...

Dim myList As New List(Of MyObject)()
myList.Add(New MyObject(1, "Outdoor"))
myList.Add(New MyObject(2, "Hardware"))
myList.Add(New MyObject(3, "Tools"))
myList.Add(New MyObject(4, "Books"))
myList.Add(New MyObject(5, "Appliances"))
RadGridView1.DataSource = myList
```

Result:

[image]

Note how the control automatically picks up the Property Names from the custom class: `MyInt` and `MyString` become column names.  That is the only layout (HOW) related thing the grid picks up from the DataSource, and thats only when `AutoGenerateColumns` is True (otherwise they would be blank).  When False, you control it by laying out the columns.

Now look at what you are attempting:

```vb
With MyRow
    .Cells(0).Value = "My Value for Column 1"
    .Cells(1).Value = "My Value for Column 2"
     ...
    .Height = 50
    .Tag = New Object
    .IsSelected = True
```

There are many problems with this as a DataSource.  Mainly, you are not supplying data for cells, but data in cells for cells.  Your approach sort of mixes the unbound approach (explicitly specify what is to go into each cell), with binding to a datasource.

But, how is it supposed to know `Value` is a data display item?  How is it supposed to know to drill into the cell collection to find `Value`?  How is it supposed to know that `Value` is data but `Tag` is not?  How is it supposed to know *not* to try to display `Height` as column data?  Just because the name matches a control's property name?

What would happen if `myObject` by chance had a `Height` property related to my class? *You* want the control to interpret it as control layout information, but the rest of the world would want the patient's height, or building height or geo formation height to show as *data*.  We would have to design classes with unique names not found in the control in order to get our data to show and prevent the control presentation from whimsically changing based on *data* and property names in the DataSource.

The `GridviewRowInfo` as the name suggests provides row *information*, not row *data*. Extensive presentation information is present in your List, but it doesnt work like you want because *controls do not use the datasource to get presentation infomation.*

---

The control does include [Four ways to customize RadGridView appearance](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-styling-and-appearance-four-ways-to-customize-radgridview-appearance.html): Themes, UI editor, Events and Conditional Formatting.

There other elements like `GridTableElement` and `GridTableBodyElement`. Actually these elements contain some properties that control behavior and appearance of grid cells and rows, like `GridTableElement.RowHeight`, `RowSpacing` and so on.

## tl;dr

Data passed in a DataSource, does not affect the presentation (aside from Column names with `AutoGenerateColumns`, but that is a function of that property, not the datasource.)

Comment: thakyou for the detailed illustration!

Answer (score 2):

RadGridView supports two ways of populating with data:

- [Unbound mode](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-unbound-mode.html) where you can manually add the columns and the rows to the grid (just like you did)
- [Bound mode](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-databinding-radgridview.html) where you set the **DataSource** property of the control to one of the supported types, namely

  - [Array and ArrayList](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-array-and-arraylist.html) of simple types or custom objects.
  - [Generic Lists](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-generic-list.html) of simple types or custom objects.
  - [BindingList or other IBindingList](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-bindinglist.html)` implementations.
  - [Database data using DataTable, DataSet](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-tutorial-binding-to-datatable-or-dataset.html) or [DataReader](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-datareader.html) components from a wide range of providers (MS SQL, Oracle, Access,
    anything accessible through OleDb).

So, you cannot bind the grid to collection of GridViewRowInfos (as you will only see the GridViewRowInfo type properties). You should either continue manually adding the as you are right now, or you can populate a DataTable for example with your data and set it as DataSource for the grid.

*All of the links and information are from the Telerik UI for WinForms documentation